# Beginner C# image loading woes - NullReferenceException

Tags: xna, c#, 2d

I keep getting a "NullReferenceExeption was unhandled" with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." written under it. **I have all of the images (png) correct with names and added to references.**

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    backGround = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Cracked");
    player1.playerBlock = Content.Load<Texture2D>("square");
    player2.playerBlock = Content.Load<Texture2D>("square2");
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare `spriteBatch` or `backGround`?  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: For one, if we're talking XNA here it's aTexture2DObject = Content.Load<Texture2D>("fileName");  Furthermore, are your objects player1 and player2 actually initialized by the time you reach this part of the code?

Comment: **The problem is with the "splayer1.playerBlock = Content.Load("square");" and "player1.playerBlock = Content.Load("square2");" lines**

Comment: Again, the player1 and player2 objects need to exist before you can modify their member variables.  Your error message is telling you that the thing you want to change doesn't even exist... so create it.  Like Player player1 = new Player();

Comment: **I looked at my initialize class and it was like this:**

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();

            
            player1 = new Player();
            player2 = new Player();
            


        }

Comment: all i needed to do was put the "base.Initialize();" under the player1 and player2 ;) TY!

Comment: Oh and Ktodisco what is a "Stack Trace?"